# Как использовать классы JS на стороне сервера?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ооп, классы

Может мой вопрос покажется глупым, но я нигде не могу получить на него ответ. Кто может подсказать как использовать классы JS на стороне сервера Node JS? Всегда писал бек-энд на Java, для меня классы и интерфейсы - это самое понятное, что придумало человечество. Начал изучать Node JS, но не могу найти ни одного примера с использованием классов JS. Я понимаю, что это лишь синтаксический сахар, но он очень сладкий, чтобы от него отказываться. Или может их вообще не используют на стороне сервера? Кто может дать ссылку где об этом почитать или привести конкретный пример, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Так же как и на фронтенде) Правда их польза на практике проявляется в экзотических случаях, можно вполне обойтись без классов) Лично мне больше нравится использовать модульный подход

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru

Answer (score 0):

App.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000


// Подключение нашего класса
const Roouter = require('./ClassTest')
// так же мы можем сразу подключить отдельную функцию чере require('./ClassTest').<функция>()


// игициалезируем переменную getRouter, из класса Roouter в переменную Var
const Var = Roouter.getRouter()


// собственно выводим сообщение из нашего класса
app.use(Var)


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

ClassTest.js

```js
// создание класса
class Router{

    getRouter() {
        const router = require('express').Router()

        return router.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))
    }

}
//експорт нашего класса
module.exports = new Router;
```

Примерно как то так я работаю с классами )